# Drawing 4 squares inside each other

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to draw 4 squares, each square get smaller by 10 pixel and goes inside the other square(centered)

this is what I have for now

square.py

```
def drawSquare(myTurtle,sideLength,x,y):
    myTurtle.setx(x)
    myTurtle.sety(y)
    for i in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(90)
```

main.py

```
>>> from square import *
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Turtle()
>>> side = 200
>>> x = 60
>>> y = 60
>>> for i in range(4):
    drawSquare(t,200,x,y)
    side = side - 10
    x = x- 5
    y = y - 5
```

Unfortunately the way this works is 4 different squares are on top of each other

any suggestions ?

Comment: You will also need to move the starting point of the turtle in between drawing the squares.

Comment: what is that called? i could not find it in the documentation

Comment: ...what is *what* called?

Comment: what is the function that moves the starting point of the turtle called ? cause if I can find it I would not need to change the x and y anymore

Comment: I suggest you re-read the documentation, which includes several options you could use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle-methods

Comment: One possible (hack) solution would be to add `myTurtle.right(90)` after `y = y - 5`. This way all squares will start in a different direction and you will get 4 non-overlapping squares. I recommend you understand what Turtle is doing, then you will find the solution! :)

Comment: Turtle programming is there not only to get your python programming rolling, but also to get you on the right approaches of learning new libraries, paradigms and approach to programming autonomously. If I were you I would take @jonrsharpe 's recommendation and re read the docs and explore ways of solving it on your own before resorting to asking how to solve it and using solutions of others like the one below. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: it turns out x has to be = x +5. so the turtle wil move inside the square, all good now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I approached this question using recursion as it is probably the most simple way.

```
myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
def drawSquares(myTurtle,sideLength, x, y, nSquares, distanceApart):
    if nSquares > 0:
        myTurtle.pu()
        myTurtle.setx(x)
        myTurtle.sety(y)
        myTurtle.pd()
        for i in range(4):
            myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
            myTurtle.right(90)
        drawSquares(myTurtle, sideLength - distanceApart*2, x+10, y-10, nSquares-1, distanceApart)

drawSquares(myTurtle, 200, 60, 60, 4, 10)
```

Comment: I like this solution (+1) but you've made the "gap" between squares twice what the OP specified and failed to use `distanceApart` as part of the recursive `x` and `y` calculation, instead using a hardcoded value of 10.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be approached several different ways using turtle.  Although the obvious answer seems to be nested loops to draw the squares, below are some other ways to think about it.

First, using `turtle.circle(steps=4)`.  The circle routine can draw arbitrary regular polygons including squares though you have to make adjustments with respect to positioning:

```
import turtle

def drawSquares(myTurtle, sideLength, nSquares, distanceApart):

    myTurtle.penup()
    x, y = myTurtle.position()
    myTurtle.goto(x - sideLength/ 2, y - sideLength / 2)  # adjust so current x, y is center
    myTurtle.pendown()

    myTurtle.setheading(-45)  # by default square would be sitting on corner instead of on side

    for _ in range(nSquares):
        radius = sideLength * 2**0.5 / 2
        myTurtle.circle(radius, steps=4)
        sideLength -= 10

        myTurtle.penup()
        x, y = myTurtle.position()
        myTurtle.goto(x + distanceApart / 2, y + distanceApart / 2)
        myTurtle.pendown()


yertle = turtle.Turtle()
yertle.penup()
yertle.goto(60, 60)
yertle.pendown()
drawSquares(yertle, 200, 4, 10)

turtle.done()
```

For my remaining examples, I'm going to assume the same calling code and just present modified `drawSquares()` routines.  I believe @PVNRT's *recursive* solution was excellent though I'd adjust it slightly as follows:

```
def drawSquares(myTurtle, sideLength, nSquares, distanceApart):
    if nSquares < 1:
        return

    for _ in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.left(90)

    myTurtle.penup()
    x, y = myTurtle.position()
    myTurtle.goto(x + distanceApart / 2, y + distanceApart / 2)
    myTurtle.pendown()

    drawSquares(myTurtle, sideLength - distanceApart, nSquares - 1, distanceApart)
```

My personal favorite way to go about this sort of problem is to use *stamping* instead of *drawing*.  It's an extremely fast solution:

```
def drawSquares(yourTurtle, sideLength, nSquares, distanceApart):
    myTurtle = yourTurtle.clone()  # clone turtle so we don't have to restore changes

    myTurtle.shape("square")  # modify turtle shape for stamping
    myTurtle.fillcolor(turtle.bgcolor())  # modify turtle fill color for stamping

    for _ in range(nSquares):
        myTurtle.turtlesize(sideLength / 20)  # magic number 20 is default stamp size
        myTurtle.stamp()
        sideLength -= distanceApart
```

And finally, the *obvious* solution using nested loops which shouldn't be as obvious going forward now that you've seen there are other approaches:

```
def drawSquares(myTurtle, sideLength, nSquares, distanceApart):

    for n in range(nSquares):

        for _ in range(4):
            myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
            myTurtle.left(90)

        myTurtle.penup()
        x, y = myTurtle.position()
        myTurtle.goto(x + distanceApart / 2, y + distanceApart / 2)
        myTurtle.pendown()

        sideLength -= distanceApart
```

One weakness in the OP's specification was the meaning of the x & y arguments.  I've left them out with the understanding that the squares are drawn at the current x & y.  The OP treated them as the upper right corner of the drawing which isn't consistent with anything in turtle.  I've chosen to make them either the lower left or the center (for the circle and stamping-based solutions.)